# Updating a gem having issues with zeitwerk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update this [gem](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) to work with rails 7 and I think that the error is due to zeitwerk. The error that's popping up is the following

```
/Users/nate/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/impressionist-2.0.0/lib/impressionist/engine.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>': uninitialized constant Impressionist::Engine::ImpressionistController (NameError)
```

and It's originating from `lib/impressionist/engine.rb` here from the lines below

```rb
module Impressionist
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    attr_accessor :orm

  initializer 'impressionist.model' do |app|
    @orm = Impressionist.orm
    include_orm
  end


  initializer 'impressionist.controller' do
    require "impressionist/controllers/mongoid/impressionist_controller" if orm == :mongoid.to_s

    ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
     include ImpressionistController::InstanceMethods <--- HERE
     extend ImpressionistController::ClassMethods <--- HERE
   end
  end


 private

    def include_orm
      require "#{root}/app/models/impressionist/impressionable.rb"
      require "impressionist/models/#{orm}/impression.rb"
      require "impressionist/models/#{orm}/impressionist/impressionable.rb"
    end

  end
end
```

I think that this first include is trying to call `app/controllers/impressionist_controller.rb`, but for some reason doesn't load with rails 7. Any ideas on how to approach fixing this? I suspect that I have to somehow incorporate zeitwerk here.

Comment: This is an open issue with the gem...https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/issues/302

Comment: 1) Did run the generate command `rails g impressionist`? 2) Have you tried changing the class reference to explicit global scope `::ImpressionistController` in the `on_load` block?

Comment: @dbugger Exactly! No one seems to be contributing...

Comment: @Casper The posted error message is the result from `rails g impressionist`. I tried to reference the global scope, but the error persists.

Comment: Nate, I cannot reproduce this problem. Installed Rails 7.0.3 with Ruby 3.0.4, Then `rails g impressionist`. Worked without any issues. Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example in your question. It needs to be the minimal possible sequence of commands that is required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Oddly enough the error doesn't seem to pop up with a fresh rails application. However there is at least two other users experiencing the same issue as I am in the issue linked by @dbugger.